# Is it possible to express a function in terms of a power series of any arbitrary function?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

A while ago a read on Twitter something about a theorem that allowed you to extend somehow the taylor saries to any arbitrary function, but I couldnt find it again and Im very interested in it. I was just wondering if anyone knows or if I just dont remember correctly what I saw. I remember it was something like this

$$  f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{inf} a_n \frac{(z-\phi (z) )^n}{n!} $$

Comment: If $\forall z, f(z) \ne 0$, there exists a function $\phi(z)$ such that $$f(z) = \sum_n \frac{(z-\phi (z) )^n}{n!}$$ but this is not a fact of great consequence, since the sum is $e^{z - \phi(z)}$ and so you can just define $\phi(z) = z - \ln(f(z))$, using your favorite branch of the logarithm. I'm wondering if maybe you are a little mistaken about the content? There is a way to use taylor series to expand the domain of a function into the complex plane. But that requires the original function have a normal taylor series representation.

Comment: I think I didnt express myself properly. I meant that the theorem states that any funcion f(z) (with some restrictions) can be expressed as the power sum of any other function \phi(z) that you like i.e. if  you have f(z) you can express it in terms of powers of sin(z) or log(z). Therefore taylor series would be the special case where \Phi(z)=z

Comment: I'm guessing then that what you were reading about is Fourier series, sums of the form $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n\cos n\omega z + b_n\sin n\omega z)$$ and mixed them with power series (note that cosine and sine are not being raised to the power fo $n$) because you can also express a Fourier series as $$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_ne^{in \omega z}$$ which is a power series of $e^{i\omega z}$. However, it is not true that every function $f(z)$ can be expressed in this fashion. $f$ has to be continuous except at isolated points, and  either periodic or of bounded domain.

Comment: I'm already quite familiar with fourier series, but that's not what im refering to.  I meant that having f(z) you could choose any \phi(z) and express f(z) ad powers of \phi(z) . I can recall that it was a pretty unknown theorem and I couldnt find it anywhere. I could also remember that the coefficients of the sum had something to do with de (n-1)th derivatived of \phi(z)

Comment: Im sorry if Im not being specific enough but thats all i can remeber

Comment: You are contradicting yourself here: you claim you can choose any function $\phi$, but then say the coefficients are from the $n-1$-th derivative of $\phi$. Which means that $\phi$ has to be infinitely differentiable, which is a property that very few functions have. And the representation requires that $f$ also be infinitely differentiable. So "any arbitrary function" is false.

Comment: I know. When I say any function I assume there may be some restrictions, as they probably need to be analytical or so. The point is that under these restriction there is not only one \phi(z) that satisfies these conditions, instead any function you choose regarding these conditions

Comment: Well then, I hope this conversation has at least taught you a little about saying things in mathematics that you don't actually mean.

Comment: But I dont know why are you focusing on the details, its evident that there must be some constraints to the functions, thats what the theorem is about, but what Im asking is if anyone knows about this theorem. The key fact of this theorem is that allows you to expand functions in terms of powers of other functions, not the constrains on this functions, so anyone knowing it would recognize what im refering to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way I found it. It is called Bürmann's theorem. Here it is:[Bürmanns Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BuermannsTheorem.html)